# WinRT and Windows phone development requirements

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am a bit confused now and need confirmation on development requirements for WinRT app and windows phone 8 app:

Are the following requirements correct?

1) For Windows Phone 8

To use the emulator of windows phone 8 in VS2010 express for Windows phone, the requirement will be:
a) Windows 8 OS Pro.  This is a MUST. 
b) Support for Hyper-V

2) For WinRT App development

2b) To use the emulator of WinRT or Emulator, Do I need to have Win8 OS Pro or just win8 OS? 
2c) To use the emulator, does it require Hyper-V? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [System requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

- OS : Windows 8 Pro or higher (64 - bit OS)
- RAM : 4 GB or higher
- For emulator : Hyper V

For WinRT Hyper-V is not required. WinRT emulator is available when VS 2012 is installed, it's part of it. So VS 2012 requirment is applicable to WinRT emulator also.

Comment: Just wondering, will there be any case that winRT app will ever required Hyper-V? It seems the best development, you need a win8 OS PRO for both worlds!

Comment: I mean will there be any case that Hyper-V will be required in testing WinRT app using VS2010 in development. Thanks

Comment: VS2010 is not supported to view/test/develop WinRT app.

Comment: Hyper-V is not required because it does not required complex emulation, the emulator is Windows 8 itself while in Windows phone the host OS is different than guest OS so it requires virtualization technique.

Answer (score 0):

If debug on device then need only Windows 8 (not Pro, not x64, not 4 GB, not Hyper-V). Works on Asus Transformer TA100.
However, on Windows 7 have not tried it ..))